# How to know whan a speceific bluetooth device is connecting?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an app that runs in the background and needs to know when a specific bluetooth device is connected. 
lets say that i want my app to run on the background and do something when your device is connected to the car bluetooth.
Thanks!

Comment: Specific device e.g. one exact unique device or specific as in class of device e.g. headset or car infotainment?

Comment: the specific one that you have in your car.  i'll have my app making you choose wich bluetooth divice from the paired list your phone has is your car bluetooth and than i want to do something when its connected to your phone.  hope im clear :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code gives the device to which it is connected

```
BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
```

Code:

```
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
    IntentFilter filter3 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter2);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter3);
}

//The BroadcastReceiver that listens for bluetooth broadcasts
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
           ... //Device found
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
           ... //Device is now connected
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
           ... //Done searching
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
           ... //Device is about to disconnect
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
           ... //Device has disconnected
        }           
    }
};
```