# Detect if there is a bluetooth device connected (android)

Tags: android, bluetooth

In my app, i have to disable bluetooth. But i don't want to do it if a device is connected to the smartphone.

So how can i do something like :
if (!areBlueDevicesConnected()))
disableBluetooth();

Actually i know how i could use Broadcast Receivers, but I'd rather not use them (like this [How to know whan a speceific bluetooth device is connecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383893/how-to-know-whan-a-speceific-bluetooth-device-is-connecting)).

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can query:

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```

This will return a set of paired devices.
If this returns your device then you can move forward for whatever task you want to achieve.